# How to use left join limit 1 in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a model:

```
class DistributorContacts extends Model
{
    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Contacts::class);
    }
}
```

I use this like:

```
$distributors = DistributorContacts::with("contracts")->whereIn("user_id", $this->id)->get();
```

Problem is that I need to get only one row from `"contracts"` ordered by date.

How to do that?

Comment: 1 row for each `DistributorContacts` ... not 1 row total, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the query to a function.

```
$distributors = DistributorContacts::with([
    'contacts' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->limit(1);
    }
])->whereIn("user_id", $this->id)->get();
```

Comment: This will produce unexpected result while mutiple id is passed to ```whereIn``` method

Answer (score 2):

> YOU MUST HAVE LARAVEL  `v8.42.0` OR ABOVE TO USE THIS FEATURE

If you need to get only one row from "contracts" ordered by date.

You can use [has-one-of-many](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many) relation. So

```
class DistributorContacts extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the DistributorContact's most recent Contacts.
     */
    public function latestContacts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contacts::class)->latestOfMany();
    }

    /**
     * Get the DistributorContact's oldest Contacts.
     */
    public function oldestContacts()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Contacts::class)->oldestOfMany();
    }
}
```

So in while querying, you can do something like this.

For **latest contact**:

```
$distributors = DistributorContacts::with("latestContacts")->whereIn("user_id", $this->id)->get();
```

For **oldest contact**:

```
$distributors = DistributorContacts::with("oldestContacts")->whereIn("user_id", $this->id)->get();
```

Related Links

1. [Pull Request #37362](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37362)
2. [Laravel News Blog Post](https://laravel-news.com/one-of-many-eloquent-relationship)
3. [Release Note](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.42.0)

Comment: I'm getting "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::oldestOfMany()" in Laravel 8.38. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The [one-of-many relationship](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/37362) was add to Framework in [v8.42.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/releases/tag/v8.42.0) release. You need to upgrade your Laravel Version to use this feature

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just checked my version to make sure, apparently I've "8.83.9" according to ` app()->version() `. Nonetheless I still get undefined method "....\BelongsToMany::oldestOfMany()" error. Are you certain you're not mixing it with `hasOne(...)->latestOfMany()` ? Because I don't see `CanBeOneOfMany` trait being used in `BelongsToMany` relationship.

Comment: Instead of ```belongsToMany``` can you try ```belongsTo``` or ```hasOne```

Comment: Sure it works with hasOne, you might want to update the answer accordingly. It is misleading since latestOfMany() is specific to hasOne relationships.

Comment: Updated my answer @Skywarth thanks for the update. If you found my answer helpful give it a upvote